# How to index NumPy array using ndenumerate?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

My code:

```
import numpy as np
nnet.temp = np.zeros(nnet.max_layer_size, dtype=np.float64)
##some code
nnet.temp[i] = temp_val
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(nnet.temp):
   print(index, x)
```

`print(nnet.temp)`:

```
[0.12233607 0.         0.19732719 0.         0.23104049 0.
 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.19245713]
[0.         2.48127313 0.         0.         0.         0.21570966
 0.         0.         0.39054759 0.         0.         0.        ]
```

As I want to print them with index I tried `ndenumerate`:

```
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(nnet.temp):
   print(index, x)
```

```
(0,) 0.12233607087416862
(1,) 0.0
(2,) 0.19732719295877543
(3,) 0.0
(4,) 0.23104048678483236
(5,) 0.0
(6,) 0.0
(7,) 0.0
(8,) 0.0
(9,) 0.0
(10,) 0.0
(11,) 0.19245712897455036
(0,) 0.0
(1,) 2.4812731271543647
(2,) 0.0
(3,) 0.0
(4,) 0.0
(5,) 0.21570965947566847
(6,) 0.0
(7,) 0.0
(8,) 0.39054758850346893
(9,) 0.0
(10,) 0.0
(11,) 0.0
```

But I want:

```
(0,0) 0.12233607087416862
(0,1) 0.0
(0,2) 0.19732719295877543
(0,3) 0.0
(0,4) 0.23104048678483236
(0,5) 0.0
(0,6) 0.0
(0,7) 0.0
(0,8) 0.0
(0,9) 0.0
(0,10) 0.0
(0,11) 0.19245712897455036
(1,0) 0.0
(1,1) 2.4812731271543647
(1,2) 0.0
(1,3) 0.0
(1,4) 0.0
(1,5) 0.21570965947566847
(1,6) 0.0
(1,7) 0.0
(1,8) 0.39054758850346893
(1,9) 0.0
(1,10) 0.0
(1,11) 0.0
```

What is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
In [146]: for idx,x in np.ndenumerate(np.zeros((3,2))):print(idx,x)                                          
(0, 0) 0.0
(0, 1) 0.0
(1, 0) 0.0
(1, 1) 0.0
(2, 0) 0.0
(2, 1) 0.0
```